# Ensuring non-expired token before every request

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication

I'm developing an iOS application where data is fetched from a third-party REST API. Each request must contain an authorization token.

In order to implement this, I've written a `fetchToken withCompletionBlock:(void (^)(ASToken*) token,NSError * error)` method in `AppDelegate`:

```
-(void) fetchTokenWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(ASToken * token, NSError * error)) completionBlock
{
    if (!_token) {
        _token = [self retrieveTokenFromKeychain];
    }

    if (!_token || _token.isExpired) {
        [ASMyApi loadTokenWithcompletionBlock:^(ASToken *token, NSError*  error) {

            if (token) {
                _token = token;
                [self saveTokenToKeychain: token];
            }else{
                completionBlock(nil,&error);
            }

        }];
    }else{
        completionBlock(_token,nil);
    }
}
```

Before every requests that requires Authorization, `fetchToken withCompletionBlock:(void (^)(ASToken*) token,NSError ** error)` is called to retrieve the token. Here's an example:

> ```
> -(IBAction) loadCategories
> {
>     [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
>     [((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) fetchTokenWithCompletionBlock:^(ASToken *token, NSError *error) {
>
>         if (token) {
>             [ASMyApi loadCategories:token.token completionBlock:^(NSArray *categories, NSError *error) {
>
>                 [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
>
>                 if (categories){
>
>                     self.categories = categories;
>
>                 }else{
>
>                     [self monitorNetworkReachability];
>
>                 }
>
>                 [self updateUI];
>
>             }];
>
>         }else{
>
>             [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
>             [self monitorNetworkReachability];
>         }
>
>     }];
> }
> ```

I'm not happy with this code for the following reasons:

- The nested nature of the callbacks makes it look ugly and somewhat unreadable
- Too much repetition: The code to get the token is verbose and must be called before each request. The failure code is also repeated.

What I do like about this approach is that it ensures that there's always a valid token before sending the request (as opposed to having the request fail, and then requesting a new token).

I'd appreciate a second-opinion on this design and input on how it might be refactored.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the outer completion block needs to be an `NSError **` exactly.  This seems confusing to me.  We usually reserve `NSError **` for when we're passing it into a method.  I don't know if I've ever seen it as a completion block argument.

Comment: My reasoning was that if `fetchTokenWithCompletionBlock: ` fails, the NSError would be passed to the completionBlock which is in the ViewController. and the ViewController would then handle the error (e.g. by displaying an alert or something). I'm quite new to iOS so it might not actually be a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, but why doesn't `NSError *` work?  Why do you need the pointer-to-pointer?

Comment: I'm looking at it and even I don't know why I did that! Sorry, that's my bad.

Comment: It seems that you only check the token in local side. However the token may be invalid in the server side for unknown reasons. So it would be better to handle token error message from server side and auto refresh token after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could introduce a delegate instead passing another block in `loadCategories` method.

First, the protocol:

```
@protocol ASMyApiCategoriesDelegate <NSObject>

    @required
    - (void) ASMyApiCategoriesDidLoad:(NSArray *)categories;
    - (void) ASMyApiCategoriesDidFailToLoadWithError:(NSError *)error

@end
```

You change the signature of `+ [ASMyApi loadCategories:completionBlock:]` to accept a delegate:

```
+ (void) loadCategoriesToken:(id)token delegate:(id <ASMyApiCategoriesDelegate>)delegate
{
    NSArray *categories;
    // code that loads categories

    if (categories)
    {
        [delegate ASMyApiCategoriesDidLoad:categories];
    }
    else
    {
        [delegate ASMyApiCategoriesDidFailToLoadWithError:nil];
    }
}
```

In your view controller you'll have to implement the required methods from `ASMyApiCategoriesDelegate` protocol and update `loadCategories` method.

```
- (void) ASMyApiCategoriesDelegateDidLoad:(NSArray *)categories
{
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    self.categories = categories;
    [self updateUI];
}

- (void) ASMyApiCategoriesDelegateDidFailToLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self monitorNetworkReachability];
}

- (IBAction) loadCategories
{
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    [((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) fetchTokenWithCompletionBlock:^(ASToken *token, NSError *error) {
        if (token)
        {
            [ASMyApi loadCategories:token.token delegate:self];
        }
        else
        {
            [self ASMyApiCategoriesDidFailToLoadWithError:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: That looks like a good way of doing it. The API loads other kind of objects besides categories e.g. products, deals e.t.c. In this case - would make sense to have one delegate with response data of type `id` or to declare a delegate for each kind of response object?

Comment: Categories, products, deals: they look like all are arrays. In this case I would use the same response for all.